# How to find the location of negative cost dicircuit with Bellman-Ford algorithm?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I know that using Bellman-Ford algorithm, it is possible to know whether there is a cycle with negative cost or not. I want to know if it is possible to know which edges form that negative cycle? Could you please help me with that?

Thanks in Advance!